# How trigger a state using the value of a useRef in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

In React, i have a form with a input and a button. I use a useRef to controll the actual value of input. I want a button be disable when input text is empty, but when a use a useRef i can't trigger a re-render. Is good practice use useState() to controll input state? Has another soluton to this case?

```
<TitleInputText
          name=''
          type='text'
          title={inputTitle} 
          placeholder={inputPlaceholder}
          onChange={(value) => (graphicName.current = value)}
        />`

`export const TitleInputText: FC<TitleInputTextProps> = ({
  title,
  type,
  name,
  placeholder,
  onChange,
}) => {
  return (
    <S.Container data-testid='title-input'>
      <Title label={title} size='small' />
      <S.InputTitleAnalytic
        type={type}
        name={name}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={(e) => {
          if (onChange) onChange(e.target.value)
        }}
      />
    </S.Container>
  )
}
```

12345678910123432112312

Answer (score 0):

its fine to use `useState` for input
also the `if (onChange) onChange(e.target.value)` can be replaced by `onChange?.(e.target.value)`

Answer (score 0):

It is good to use controlled component, instead of uncontrolled component.
You can code like this.

```js
const [value, setValue] = useState("");

...

<form>
    <button disabled={value === ""}>BUTTON</button>
    <input value={value} onChange={e=>setValue(e.target.value)}></input>
</form>
```